# Let G = <x> be a cyclic group of order 24. List all the elements in G that are of order 4.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let G =  be a cyclic group of order 24. List all the elements in G that are of order 4.

The only relevant theorems in my book that I can find is:

The order of a group G, denoted by |G|, is the number of elements in G.

If G = , then |G| = o(x).

I'm not sure where to go with this. From the first theorem, I'm led to believe that the elements would just be $x^1, x^2, x^3, x^4$. Is this correct?

Comment: @lhf Abstract Algebra A First Course Second Edition by Dan Saracino

Comment: The answer follows directly from Theorem 4.4 (iii) in that book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Here are the relevant elementary facts:

- All elements of $G=\langle x \rangle$ are of the form $x^k$ with $k\in \{0,1,\dots,23\}$.
- If $o(x^k)=4$, then $(x^k)^4=1$.
- If $x^m=1$, then $m$ is a multiple of $o(x)=24$.

Comment: I got o(x^k) = 4 = o(x)/(k,o(x)) = 24/(k,24)
This implies gcd(k,24) = 6
k must be 6 and 18
so the elements are x^6 and x^18.
Should there be more?

Comment: they are the only ones